# Cannot retrieve any values using equalTo() query Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chat app and this is what my Database looks like:
[image: Please, click here to see]

So, I currently have a `users` node as well as a `chats` node.

The `users` node saves the last **last login date** and the **chats Ids** that the user is currently part of. In the `chats` node, it is saved the **User Ids** that make part of the conversation as well as the **messages** which have an **Id**, **Content**, **Send Date**, and **User who sent**.

Currently I am building the activity where it is displayed the conversations that the user is part of (using a recyclerview).

To be able to know what conversations the user is part of, instead of retrieving all conversations, I retrieve the **chats ids** that are in the `user` node and I put them all in an `ArrayList<String>`.

[image: Here is a picture that helps you see what goes in the ArrayList]

The code that retrieves those Ids and puts them in the ArrayList is this:

```
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                p0.children.forEach{
                    chatsId.add(it.key.toString()) // ChatsId is the ArrayList<String>
                }
                getChats2()
            }

        })
```

And this code works like a charm.
The problem comes when I try to query the `chats` node just to retrieve the chat that has the value equal to the values retrieved in the code above.
** That code is implemented in the getsChat2() **:

```
 db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats")

        // For each chatId, queries the DB to find the chat reference
        chatsId.forEach {
            val query = db.equalTo(it)
            query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    p0.children.forEach {it2->
                        println("Do something")
                        // Do something with the chat reference
                    }
                }

            })
        }
```

The problem is, even if there is a node with the same value as the `chatsId` variable, the `println("Do Something)` never actually prints.

Comment: `chatsId` is an ArrayList that contains all the chat keys that are stored in the database inside the current `user` node

Comment: this is wrong `val query = db.equalTo(it)`. The `db` is equal to the reference parent node `chats` and `chats` is not equal to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do, but my educated guess is that you're missing an `orderByKey()` call:

```
val query = db.orderByKey().equalTo(it)
```

When you don't call any `orderBy...()` method, the nodes are sorted on their priority. That's a left-over from the early days of the API that has very little practical use, so these days it mostly means that you must call `orderBy...()` before filtering.

Comment: You got it! Thanks a lot!